# Running into 'typeerror math.random is not a function' when running a function with javascript. Please advise

Tags: javascript, typeerror, discord.js

So the jist of it is, I'm writing some code for a discord bot I have running. I did this all on my own so sorry if it's sloppy. The main problem is I'm running into the aforementioned 'typeerror math.random is not a function' whilst running it. This would be fine if the other classes with very similar code didn't look exactly the same and run perfectly.

I already searched for any missing semicolons or misplaced bits in the code. However, as I specified this code runs perfectly fine on other similar and nearly identical classes.

This is the most important section of the code. The rest is generally just sending all the messages out more than anything.

```js
 //list of general weather conditions
       var fallcondition = ["light rainfall", "Cloudy skies", "Sunny skies"];
       var windy = ["North", "West", "East", "South"];
       var bounty = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);


       // gets the length of each list
       var fallLen = fallcondition.length;
       var windlen = windy.length;


       //randomly genorates temperatures for each season based on the max, all but winter should within a certain range
       //FAR stands for farienheit
       var randfalltemp = Math.floor(Math.random() (17 - 4 + 1) + 4);
       var fallFAR = (randfalltemp * 9/5) + 32;

       //Gets random wind speed
       var windspd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);

       //Genorates all the random weather conditions based on length
       var randnumfall = Math.floor(Math.random() * fallLen);
       var randwind = Math.floor(Math.random() * windlen);

       //puts random number values into lists
       var windDir = windy[randwind];
```

And if you're curious this is what the working code looks like. As I said, it is identical aside form the names and the NEW bounty variable

```js
 //list of general weather conditions
        var summercondition = ["Cloudy skies", "partly cloudy skies", "Sunny skies"];

        var windy = ["North", "West", "East", "South"];

        // gets the length of each list
        var summerlen = summercondition.length;
        var windlen = windy.length;

        //randomly genorates temperatures for each season based on the max, all but winter are within a certain range
        //FAR stands for farienheit
        var randsumtemp = Math.floor(Math.random() * (35 - 20 + 1) + 20);
        var sumFAR = (randsumtemp * 9/5) + 32;

        //Gets random wind speed
        var windspd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12.4);

        //Genorates all the random weather conditions based on length
        var randnumsum = Math.floor(Math.random() * summerlen);
        var randwind = Math.floor(Math.random() * windlen);

        //puts random number values into lists
        var windDir = windy[randwind];
```

The end result of the program is that the message should send. As it is now it only sends an error report rather than the message that is supposed to show up (there is a later if statement depending on the value)

If there is any other additional comments or whatnot then I would appreciate the advice.

Comment: Here: `var randfalltemp = Math.floor(Math.random() (17 - 4 + 1) + 4);` a missing operator after `Math.random()`. JS tries to execute a function it expects `Math.random` to return.

Comment: Thanks! that worked wonders. Can't believe I didn't see that @Teemu